# No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID xxxxxxx were found

Tags: ios, xcode

My problem is that the team ID its showing me where the xxxxxxxx is in the title is not familiar to me.  I can go to my developer profile and look at my team ID and its not what xcode is saying in the error.

I tried revoking my certificate and creating a new provisioning profile with the new cert but it still tells me the same error with the same unfamiliar team ID.

I dont know where it is getting that team id or where I can change it if i can but I do know it's not associated with my account (at least according the the developer center)

Can anyone help me fix this, I've been searching for a solution for a while and cant find any answers.

Comment: Please search on the error. This has been asked and covered many many times already.

Comment: Why do you assume I didn't do a lot of searching already? I did, I have found mentions of this issue but none which lead to a solution.  I don't think it's unheard of on SO to link someone to a resource or a question which might be helpful so you might have done that but it seems every question I ask on here needs to have one intentionally unhelpful reply

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure the bundle ID is correct?  I think it will show you Team ID's that are valid for the bundle prefix.

Comment: the bundle id is what I would expect, what is supposed to show me team IDs that are valid?  The developer center?  Or something in xcode? thanks

Comment: Not sure, just remember last time I saw funny team ID, it was because the bundle ID had been changed.  There is "Team" pop-up menu under the bundle ID setting.  Try choosing the right one.